# Extending progress control in video.js, duplicate progress bars

Tags: javascript, video.js

I'm having an issue when I extend the progressControl object it also clones the slider, so there is currently two. Am I wrong in trying to approach this by extending progressControl or should I go about creating the element a different way?

```
this.player = videojs("id", videojsOptions);
var thePlayer = this.player;

videojs.TrimVideo = videojs.ProgressControl.extend({
    init: function(player, options){
        videojs.ProgressControl.call(this, player, options);
    }
});

this.player.controlBar.progressControl.trimVideo = this.player.controlBar.progressControl.addChild(
    new videojs.TrimVideo(thePlayer, {
        el: videojs.Component.prototype.createEl(null, {
            className: 'vjs-trim-start-button vjs-menu-button',
            innerHTML: '<div style="">words and words</div>',
            role: 'button'
        })
    })
);
```

[image: Mini progress control under new element]

[Link to Progress Control documentation](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/stable/docs/api/vjs.ProgressControl.md)

[Have created a jsfiddle that replicates the behaviour](http://jsfiddle.net/tmonhyjs/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When initialising a new [progressControl](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/master/src/js/control-bar/progress-control/progress-control.js) it merges the children together, you have to explicitly set seekBar to false. So you would end up with something like

```
this.player.controlBar.progressControl.trimVideo = this.player.controlBar.progressControl.addChild(
    new videojs.TrimVideo(thePlayer, {
        el: videojs.Component.prototype.createEl(null, {
            className: 'vjs-trim-start-button vjs-menu-button',
            innerHTML: '<div style="">words and words</div>',
            role: 'button'
        }),
        seekBar: false, // either this
        children: {seekBar: false} // or this
    })
);
```